# Equivariant quantum cohomology and K-theory of vector bundles over a Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

Consider a sum of m copies of the tautological bundle over the Grassmannian of n-planes in complex k-dimensional vector space. There is an obvious action of an (m+k)-dimensional torus T on the total space of this bundle. Did anybody compute the T-equivariant quantum cohomology ring of this space? Or perhaps T-equivariant quantum K-theory?

Comment: The center of $GL_k$ acts in the same way as the diagonal in the $m$-dimensional torus. So, your action has 1-dimensional kernel. 

Comment: (Oops, I had a wrong comment based on misreading $k$ vs. $n$ -- the literature I read all has $k$-planes in $n$-space, not the reverse.)